# Control reached end of Non Void Function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to call this recursive method,but I don't understand why it's not reaching the else statement to return mul. I am passing value 0,in the main function,which is less than n,and on x becoming greater than n,it should move to else function.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int n,mul=0;
vector <int> a;

int calc(int x)
{   int mul,chk;

int l=n;
if(x<n)
{   
    chk=a[x]*(l-1);
    l--;
    if(mul<chk)
        {
            mul=chk;
    }

  calc(x+1);
        }

  else  
   { return mul;}

  }

int main() {

cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
sort(a.begin(),a.end());

int z=calc(0);
cout<<z;

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: "it's not reaching the else statement". There is no "else" keyword anywhere in your sample code.

Comment: Formatting your code properly, will make it much easier to diagnose the source of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wihtout knowing the exact error message, I am not 100% sure what is the problem, but I guess it is the following:

Your function looks like this (simplified):

```
int calc(int x) {
    if(someCondition){   
        if(otherCondition){}
        calc(x+1);
    } else {
        return mul;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if `someCondition` is `true`, the function does not return anything. You probably want to do:

```
return calc(x+1);
```

instead of just

```
calc(x+1);
```